# What is your list of programs to install to Windows after a fresh install?

Tags: linux, windows

I am looking for others' list of program that absolutely must be installed to a fresh install of Windows before going any further.  I hope to compile a list here to use as reference for all new Windows installs/restores.  Automating this list of programs installation is the next step.

---

Some great lists so far!  I will continue to monitor this and then make a list of everything I use.  Another thought, has anyone come up with a way to automate this?  Possibly going to each programs download page, downloading the most recent version, and installing?  I may way on this as well, any ideas would be appreciated!

As far as the type of machine, most of mine are hybrids i.e- server, workstation, development machine.  So all of the above!

Comment: This depends on your environment, hardware manufacturer, etc. Can you provide some more details, such as what type of computers (say servers vs. workstation), purpose of the system...

Comment: This is a poll and should be marked as Community Wiki

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Basically, here is my software list (maybe not completly up to date) :

**Edition**

- [Pspad](http://www.pspad.com): A free and really powerful editor.
- [NVU](http://www.nvu.com): An HTML editor.
- [Kompozer](http://kompozer.net): The NVU bug-fixes release.

**System**

- [Process Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/sysinternals/ProcessesAndThreads/ProcessExplorer.mspx): Replace the default windows task manager by Process Explorer!
- [Autoruns](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/sysinternals/ProcessesAndThreads/Autoruns.mspx): Want to know what is launched when Windows starts? Try autoruns!
- [CubicExplorer](http://www.cubicreality.com/): An alternative to the Windows Explorer, with bookmarks, tabs...
- [Supercopier](http://supercopier.sfxteam.org/): Replace the default copy tool of Windows.
- [Unlocker](http://ccollomb.free.fr/unlocker/): A process is locking a resource on your disk? Use unlocker to solve this problem.
- [Console²](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console): Change the DOS command for Console², with tabs, better UI...
- [Taskbar shuffle](http://www.freewebs.com/nerdcave/taskbarshuffle.htm): Rearrange the programs on your Windows taskbar by dragging and dropping them.

**Tools**

- [Stroke It](http://www.tcbmi.com/strokeit/): Execute commands, start programs only with a mouse gesture! Magic!
- [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/fr/): A free file archiver.
- [Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/): A copy-paster manager, to not be limited to one element in your clipboard.
- [Dirkey](http://www.protonfx.com/dirkey/): Use Ctrl-0 to Ctrl-9 to access your preferred directories on your disks on Windows Explorer.
- [Print screen](http://www.gadwin.com/printscreen/): A free tool to create screenshots, with a lot of options...
- [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/): Type Ctrl-Space, then write the first letters of the application, and it's launched!
- [Keybreeze](http://www.keybreeze.com/): Almost the same thing as Launchy.
- [PDF Creator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/): To transform any document to the PDF format (a new printer is added in your configuration).

**Development**

- [Tortoise CVS](http://www.tortoisecvs.org/): A CVS extension for Windows Explorer.
- [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/): Java development IDE.
- [Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/): Another Java development IDE, much better as Eclipse when you need to create Java application with Swing (this is my opinion ;o) ).

**Multimedia**

- [Foobar 2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/): A powerful media player. But needs a lot of configuration...
- [XnView](http://perso.orange.fr/pierre.g/xnview/frdownload.html): A powerful image viewer. Also offers lot of conversion controls.

**Internet**

- [Mozilla Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/): THE browser.
- [Mozilla Thunderbird](http://www.mozilla.org/): A really good email reader.
- [Trillian](http://www.ceruleanstudios.com/), [Koolim](http://www.koolim.com/), [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/) (ex Gaim), [Meebo](http://www.meebo.com/) (online): Instant Messenger tool.

**Firefox plugin**

- [Colorzilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/271): A color picker, to find out the color code of any part of the current page.
- [Download statusbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/26): A download manager.
- [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/1843): An extension for Javascript or CSS debugging. An extension for Internet Explorer that does almost the same thing: [IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&DisplayLang=en).
- [IE Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/1419): View pages with the Internet Explorer engine.
- [Measure It](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/539): A ruler to measure web components of a page.
- [PDF download](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/636): A PDF manager.
- [Sage](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/77): A RSS Viewer.
- [Stop or reload](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/313): Stop and Reload buttons are now located on the same button.
- [Tab mix plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/1122): Options for tabs management.
- [Web developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/60): Lot of tools for web development.

**Edited to add links, as requested.**

Comment: How about adding some links, to make this answer even more useful?

Comment: Hurray, Finally in Ditto I seem to have found a replacement for my top utility of all time coodclip.

Comment: I used taskix for taskbar shuffling; it's smaller.

Answer (score 8):

- [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)
- [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)
- [gvim](http://www.vim.org/)
- [sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx) esp. [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)

Comment: +1 on sysinternals.  I don't go anywhere without 'em!

Comment: you can always (if not firewalled ;-)) access sysinternals at \\live.sysinternals.com\tools

Comment: Yes! gVim FTW! +1

Answer (score 6):

Don't forget an anti-virus (fox example Avast) and a PDF reader...

By the way, if you're only reading PDF, do **not** install Acrobat Reader but a lighter PDF reader like [Foxit reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/reader/). You will gain a lot of time while opening PDF !

Comment: +1 for the Foxit reader reference... one of the first programs I install!

Answer (score 5):

I would just add

- [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) - excellent file manager, also works as ftp client and more

Comment: +1 Total Commander the very very first thing I install. Always.

Comment: +1 Love TC.  One of the first things I install also.  I really like the FTP feature....but thats one of the many.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to some of those mentioned above: [MagicDisk](http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-magicdisc-overview.htm).  It mounts ISO images in Windows so it isn't necessary to burn a bunch of CDs/DVDs.  And it's freeware.

Comment: What are the advantages of this over Daemon Tools?  I have been using DT for a long time, but I'm interested in MagicDisk.

Comment: +1 I have been using Daemon Tools until Wk8 R2 RC as that does not work on the win7 base. MagicDisk just works! Which it had integrated Explorer functionality for doubleclick->mount, but who can complain for a free Delphi program that works on the Win7 base!

Answer (score 3):

- putty
- winscp
- SciTE
- 7zip
- Java
- Python
- JEdit
- unxutils
- vlc
- firefox
- OpenOffice
- PasswordSafe
- TrueCrypt

Comment: Based on some of your tools, why not cygwin? Takes care of what putty and unxutils usually handle.

Comment: I don't like cygwin. Its just a personal preference, I'm not anti cygwin. And I like putty more then doing ssh on the command line, if only because of sensible copy and paste.

Comment: +1 for putty over cygwin. I know cygwin is great for some, its just a personal preference.  

I recommend using Putty Connection Manager in conjunction with Putty: http://puttycm.free.fr/

Answer (score 3):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)

Answer (score 3):

Every computer:

- latest video drivers
- Symantec Endpoint 11 (antivirus)
- Lavasoft Ad-Aware
- Royale theme for WinXP (integrated in my install disc)
- OpenType Font File Properties extension (Microsoft)
- User Profile Hive Cleanup (Microsoft)
- Windows Media Player 11
- Microsoft Management Console 3.0
- ThumbView Lite, PSP Thumbnail Handler, VTF Shell extensions
- Matroska shell extension
- Taskbar Shuffle
- Visual Tasktips
- IconViewer
- Kel's Vista Drive Indicator
- Windows Media Player Tag Support Extender
- Combined Community Codec Pack
- SHN Plugin (another codec)
- DirectX 9.0 Web Setup
- Internet Explorer 8
- ODF Addin for MS Office
- Psychedelia Visualizations Pack for Windows Media Player
- Save as PDF and XPS for MS Office
- Nero Burning Rom
- O&O Defrag Professional 11
- APC Powerchute Personal Edition
- Quicktime
- everything from Sysinternals
- Daemon Tools
- Adobe Acrobat Pro
- Process Tamer
- Paint.NET
- Adobe SVG Viewer (until IE supports SVG natively)
- Unlocker 1.8.7
- WinRAR
- WinSplit Revolution

My computer:

- ClipX
- FileZilla
- Virtual PC 2007
- Microsoft Pro Photo Tools
- Firefox, Opera, and Safari (for cross-browser testing)
- Windows Mobile emulator
- Blackberry emulator
- Dexpot 1.4
- FeedReader
- Google Earth
- hextreme
- icoFx
- Notepad+
- Oomph microformats plugin for Internet Explorer
- Mozilla Prism
- Spiceworks
- uTorrent

There's probably more that I can't remember.

Comment: Yikes! Isn't that a little bit excessive for "every system"? For instance, I haven't seen a web app that uses SVG in at least 3+ years.

Comment: I have some of it included in my slipstreamed install disc. It's a lot of stuff, but most is fairly unobtrusive and nice to have just in case.

Answer (score 2):

[TreeSize Free](http://www.jam-software.com/freeware/index.shtml).

Gotta have it. It keeps my disk usage in check.

Answer (score 2):

Scott Hanselman's maintained ["Ultimate Developer and Power Users Tool List for Windows"](http://www.hanselman.com/tools)
It was recently updated for 2009 and has many good tools and programs.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my list.

**Development**

- [**E-Texteditor**](http://www.e-texteditor.com/) - Light text editor with similar capabilities to textmate on the Mac. Great for fast editing. It's also opensource.
- [**Netbeans**](http://www.netbeans.org/) - Great for debugging code, refactoring and general coding. I use this  most of the time.
- [**Adobe Fireworks**](http://www.adobe.com/products/fireworks/) - Good graphics editor. It's not too pricey, but comes with the essentials for web graphics. Photoshop is overboard here.
- [**Charles Proxy**](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) - Allows me to debug web connections, simulate slower connections, dynamically rewrite cookies and lots of other cool stuff.
- [**Putty**](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) - No description needed (SSH Client).
- [**Virtualbox**](http://www.virtualbox.org/) - Free virtualisation software (Thanks Sun / Oracle). Allows one to mimic your production environment on your desktop (Great for learning Linux too).
- [**Win SCP**](http://winscp.net/) - Open source freeware SFTP, FTP and SCP client for Windows.

**Media**

- [**Spotify**](http://spotify.com/) - All the music you want (for free).
- [**VLC Media Player**](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) - Plays most files, lean and stable.

**Browsers**

- Safari, Chrome, Firefox and Internet explorer all for testing my weblayouts.

**Utilities**

- [**Imgburn**](http://www.imgburn.com/) - The defacto standard for creating, burning and ripping image (ISO, etc ...) files.
- [**CCleaner**](http://www.ccleaner.com/) - Removes a lot of the junk programs leave around your computer. Reclaim GB's :)
- [**Truecrypt**](http://www.truecrypt.org/) - Keeps files *very* secure.
- [**Adobe Reader**](http://get.adobe.com/reader/) - Esssential for reading PDF files.

**Firefox + Extensions**

- XDebug Helper - Tool to start/stop debug and profiling with PHP's Xdebug...
- XPath Checker - An interactive editor for XPath expressions.
- Web Developer Toolbar - Adds a menu and a toolbar with various web developer tools.
- Smush.it - Now included in YSlow 2
- YSlow 2 - YSlow analyzes web pages and why they're slow based on Yahoo!'s rules for high performance web sites
- AdBlock Plus - Ever been annoyed by all those ads and banners on the internet that often take longer to download than everything else on the page?
- Firebug - Firebug integrates with Firefox to put a wealth of development tools at your fingertips while you browse. You can edit, debug, and monitor CSS, HTML, and JavaScript live in any web page.
- FireCookie - Firecookie is an extension for Firebug that makes possible to view and manage cookies in your browser
- Live HTTP Headers - View HTTP headers of a page

**Version Control**

- [**Tortoise SVN**](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) - Good SVN client for Windows. It's stable and works well.
- [**Bazaar**](http://bazaar-vcs.org/) - Bazaar have a native client for Windows. Very easy to use, great alternative to git with it's horrible URLs.
- [**Tortoise GIT**](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) - Not as stable as one hopes, but it's a good solid effort, should improve with time.

**Messaging**

- [**Digsby**](http://www.digsby.com/) - Fantastic multi-IM client. Supports all the popular protocols. To avoid using the InstallQ variation, use the [**Digsby Offline Install**](http://www.digsby.com/download.php?os=win) (Link at bottom in small text).

Ps, that's about it. Hope someone found this useful.

Answer (score 2):

I cant believe only two mentions of VLC.  It plays anything you can throw at it!

Answer (score 1):

- [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome)
- [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)
- [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)
- [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/)
- [PDF Reader](http://www.adobe.com/go/EN_US-H-GET-READER)
- [Flash](http://www.adobe.com/go/EN_US-H-GET-FLASH)
- [Video LAN](http://www.videolan.org/)

Answer (score 1):

> Another thought, has anyone come up with a way to automate this? Possibly going to each programs download page, downloading the most recent version, and installing?

Check out [InstallPad](http://installpad.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Lately I've been installing [inSSIDer](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider) virtually as a matter of course on any computer with a wireless card, to troubleshoot the inevitable connection problems.

Answer (score 1):

[This is a list for my computer](http://www.logaholic.de/2009/05/03/my-very-own-lamp-development-tool-list-for-windows/), i recently blogged. It is divided in "misc dev tools", "specific dev tools", "communication/support" and "music/media"

Answer (score 1):

I would **first install Antivirus** and update the definitions. Second, update **Windows** with all **Security Patches** before installing any other application. 
 The order may change but these are the first step on my every new Windows Installation. Applications can wait.. the first thing is *Security* and thats what matter the most.

Answer (score 0):

AV and a decent web browser on every computer, all the rest depends on why it is being used for.

For home use: video player, music player and some office suite is usually all that is *really* needed.

Answer (score 0):

- Winsplit Revolution
- UltraMon
- Google Chrome
- Dropbox
- Python
- Bazaar

Answer (score 0):

- [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/firefox/)

  - [Download Status bar](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/26) plugin
- [Perl](http://perl.org) ( [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) or [Activestate Perl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/)
- [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)
- [Open Office](http://www.openoffice.org/)
- [Latest Updates](http://windowsupdate.microsoft.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably worth a look:

http://www.edugeek.net/forums/windows/33853-logistix-update-packs-apr09.html

Pre-packaged archives for Windows XP updates, Flash, Shockwave, PDF, Media Player, Quicktime and Real plugins and MS Office viewer and compatibility packs.

Answer (score 0):

Programs I will install as the first, before going any further:

On any machine:

- Firefox
- Chrome
- MagicISO

Home:

- Thunderbird

On a machine for developing:

- Visual Studio 2008 Express or Professional
- MSSQL Server 2005 Express or 2008 Developer Edition
- Programmer's Notepad
- Subversion
- TortoiseSVN
- AnkhSVN
- VirtualPC
- MikTeX

Work:

- Microsoft Office + Visio

Answer (score 0):

I've put my [list of standard windows software](http://delicious.com/DavidSchmitt/stdsw?sort=alpha&order=asc) on delicious. For Linux I've got it in the convenient form of a [puppet](http://reductivelabs.com/trac/puppet/wiki) [module](http://git.black.co.at/?p=module-dbp) that configures a host as I want it.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, only two mentions of anti-virus software.

I use avast or antivir, depending on the mood I am in. Lately I've been going with avast more often then not.

- avast!
- Mozilla Firefox
- Google Chrome
- Pidgin
- Putty
- notepad2

Those are my defaults, depending on what I do with the machine I will do more or less developer stuff.

Answer (score 0):

- avast!
- Firefox

  - AdBlock Plus
  - ColorZilla
  - Fast Dial
  - Faviconize Tab
  - IE Tab
  - LastPass
  - Menu Editor
  - Tab Mix Plus
- Notepad++
- ATNotes
- Timesnapper
- Cropper
- DisplayFusion
- Filezilla
- Unlocker

Answer (score 0):

[Infra Recorder](http://infrarecorder.org) - create/manipulate CD, DVD, ISO

Answer (score 0):

Aside from pretty much all the above some, others i think are unique to my windows installs:

putty connection manager (multiple PuTTY instances w/ multiple windows) - http://puttycm.free.fr/

Growl (for windows)

Pidgin

Powershell

ISO Recorder v 2

VMware Server

Answer (score 0):

For workstations and laptops for teachers and students at my workplace:

- Service Packs for the OS
- MS Office 2007
- MS Office Compatibility Packs
- MS Office Get Started for Word, Excel, Powerpoint
- VLC media player
- Voxit Budgie Pro, Text-to-speech system
- Skrivestøtte, aide for dyslectics and other challenged students
- Infrarecorder, CD burning software
- Adobe Reader 9 and all updates
- Flash and updates
- Touchlærer'n, touch typing training
- Trend Micro Officescan, antivirus

I won't hand over a computer without these. All other programs are optional, depending of the intended use for the computer.

It really seems that all of you guys are sysadmins for other sysadmins or developers...